# Need help creating a responsive footer filled with images

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a footer, filled with images, yet can't find a way to make it look nice on PC & on media devices.

I want the bronze sponsor kitten to go nicely to the left & supporter kittens to go right, while maintaining a reasonable height for a footer.

I've tried grid system, but can't get the bronze sponsor kitten's photo to stay in reasonable size, or the photos go out of container & the footer becomes bigger than my whole webpage.
and i've never used flexbox before.

```css
footer .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.bronze-container {
    max-width: 300px;
}
.sponsor-container {
}
.othersupporter {
  background: white;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.othersupporter > p {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1px;
  flex: 1 0 15%;
}
.row h4 {
    padding-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<footer style='background-color:white; width:100%; height:250px'>
    <div class='container' style='max-width:1024px; height:250px'>
        <div class='bronze-container'>
            <div class='row text-center' >
                <h4 >Bronze Sponsor </h4>
            </div>
            <div class='row text-center'>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img" alt="...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br class="visible-m"/>
        <div class='sponsor-container'>
            <div class="row text-center" >
                <h4>Supporters</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="othersupporter">
                <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
                <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
                <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
                <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
                <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
                <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
                <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
                <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
                <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
                <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: More information is needed to answer this question. Visual mock-ups would be best. Narrowing the scope of the problem would also help. What's the exact issue you're having? Also, if you want to bronze sponsor on the left and the others on the right, why do you have a line break between them?

Answer (score 1):

Your `flex-wrap` declaration on `footer .container` was causing them to stack vertically instead of sitting side-by-side. I switched out the `max-width` on `.bronze-container` and replaced it with a `flex` declaration that sets the basis at 200px, which I felt looked reasonable in the preview here. You'll probably want to adjust that for your implementation.

```css
footer .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.bronze-container {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}

.sponsor-container {}

.othersupporter {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.othersupporter > p {
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1 0 15%;
}

.row h4 {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <footer>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='bronze-container'>
        <div class='row text-center'>
          <h4>Bronze Sponsor </h4>
        </div>
        <div class='row text-center'>
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
      <br class="visible-m" />
      <div class='sponsor-container'>
        <div class="row text-center">
          <h4>Supporters</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="othersupporter">
          <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
          <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
          <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
          <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
          <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
          <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
          <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
          <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
          <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
          <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZA7mKts.png" class="card-img    " alt="..."></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```